# Merge two reflectance layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, landsat

I currently have two Landsat 5 reflectance value layers that were calculated from the per-processing function in SCP for QGIS. I would like to merge these two images together to create one mosaic layer which can be used for an NDVI calculation. Is this possible? Any time I try to complete this, I still have a white space in the overlapping portion of the images.

The images I am trying to merge:
[image: The layers I am trying to merge]

The files selected in the merge tool options:

[image]

The merge settings:

[image]

My incorrect results:

[image]

Comment: Does one of the original layers (probably the one to the NE) contain no data values where the white strip shows up?

Comment: Yes, it does contain no data in the white strip

Comment: OK, gotcha. Does nodata=0 in the original and merged datasets? If so, does setting nodata=0 to not display fix the problem? Or are you actually missing data in the merged dataset?

Comment: No I am actually missing data in the merged dataset

Comment: Just to clarify, does the original layer have nodata in this same location?

Comment: Yes, the borders of the original images are "nodata" in these locations